# jqtransform dynamic select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using jqtransform plugin to create select input, i make some change in js file i am creating a select option instead of li and i create a differente script to get select option innerhtml but when i calling this function on window.onload function is working for not working second time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta name="gmapkey" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqtransformplugin/jqtransform.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="requiered/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js" ></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('form').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function change () {

var jAm= document.getElementById('sltnew');

var jM= jAm.options[jAm.selectedIndex].text;

document.getElementById('catch').innerHTML=jM;


}


document.ajay.sltnew.onchange=change;


    </script>





</head>
<body>

    <form action="post.php" method="POST" name="ajay">
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Input Text:</label><input type="text" name="inputtext"/></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Input Password:</label><input type="password" /></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Checkbox: </label><input type="checkbox" name="chbox" id=""></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Radio :</label> 
            <input type="radio" id="" name="question" value="oui" checked ><label>oui</label>
            <input type="radio" id="" name="question" value="non" ><label>non</label></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Textarea :</label> <textarea cols="40" rows="12" name="mytext"></textarea></div>

        <div class="rowElem">
            <label>Select :</label>
            <select name="select">
                <option value="">1</option>
                <option value="opt1"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="rowElem" style="float:left; width:500px; position:relative">
            <label>Select Redimentionné :</label>

            <select name="sltnew" id="sltnew" onchange="change ()">
                <option value="opt1">Select states</option>
                <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="opt4">Option 4</option>
                <option value="opt5">Option 5</option>
                <option value="opt6">Option 6</option>
                <option value="opt7">Option 7</option>
                <option value="opt8">Option 8</option>
            </select>
            <div id="catch">select city</div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowElem"><label>Submit button:</label><input type="submit" value="Envoyer" /></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Reset button:</label><input type="reset" value="Annuler" /></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Input button:</label><input type="button" value="bouton" /></div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

change in jqtransform file what i made.

```
$wrapper.prepend('<div><span></span><a href="#" class="jqTransformSelectOpen"></a></div><select id="slt"></select>');
        var $ul = $('select', $wrapper).css('width',$select.width()).hide();
        /* Now we add the options */
        $('option', this).each(function(i){
            var oLi = $('<option><a href="#" index="'+ i +'">'+ $(this).html() +'</a></option>');
            $ul.append(oLi);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this
http://www.pkoretic.net/csTransPie